# How do I update the GUI label from WCF callback class?

Tags: c#, wcf, user-interface, callback

I'm trying to figure out how to access a method in my GUI Class: WinClient, from my WCF callback Class: MyCallBack. The method `MyCallBack.JoinServiceCallback(string message)` is working, for example if I use `MessageBox.Show(message);` it works.

I have a method in the GUI class, `SetLabelMsg(string message){}`. But I just can't figure out how to access it from the callback class. I am relatively new to C# and I have been looking at Delegate and threads and invoke. But I just can't seem to connect the dots. Hopefully someone is able to help me!

```
//this method should change te text of the GUI label
public class MyCallBack : IServiceCallback
{
    //this method should change the text of the GUI label
    public void JoinServiceCallback(string message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message + " joined the service");
    }
}


public partial class WinClient : Form
{
    public void SetLabelMsg(string message)
    {
        lblMsg.Text = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit unsure of what you are asking here. Have you generated a proxy class that can access your service yet? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes, the WCF service is working fine with tcp and httpDualBinding. I have a callback from the service that sends a message to all clients. The problem is it's in the callback type class. I just need it to set a label text on the Winform, insted of open a messageBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some great help from a fellow student.

```
public class MyCallBack : IServiceCallback
{
    private static Action<string> _changeText = null;

public static void SetDelegate(Action<string> nAction)
{
    _changeText = nAction;
}

public void JoinServiceCallback(string message)
{
    if(_changeText != null)
    {
        _changeText(message);
    }
}
}


public partial class WinClient : Form
{

public WinClient(Customer customer)
{
    MyCallBack.SetDelegate(SetLabelMsg);

    public void SetLabelMsg(string message)
    {
        lblMsg.Text = message;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly and based on the information provided. I would define a `delegate` that can recieve the message. Then define an `event` that uses it in the `MyCallBack` class.

```cs
/// <summary>Represents the method that can recieve a message.</summary>
/// <param name="message">The message.</param>
internal delegate void SendMessage(string message);

/// <summary>Occurrs when the JoinServiceCallback method is invoked.</summary>
public event SendMessage AfterJoinServiceCallback;
```

Once you have that the form can attach to the `AfterJoinServiceCallback` event on the and then `JoinServiceCallback` can raise the event.

```
if (AfterJoinServiceCallback != null)
{
    AfterJoinServiceCallback(message)
}
```

**### BEGIN EDIT ###**

I think the issue may have been that my original example defined 2 parameters on the delegate declaration but the invocation only passed the `message`.

I am glad you got something to work, however, if you end up with multiple places in the UI that need to be notified when `JoinServiceCallback` is invoked you should really look at [Using Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Using a delegate, the invocation from within `JoinServiceCallback` method would be identical but would invoke all attached target methods in the order they were attached.

```cs
public partial class WinClient : Form
{
    public WinClient()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Attach the "SetLabelMsg" method to the event
        MyCallBack.AfterJoinServiceCallback += SetLabelMsg;

        // Attach the "ShowMessage" method to the event
        MyCallBack.AfterJoinServiceCallback += ShowMessage;
    }

    private void SetLabelMsg(string message)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            // Update the status label
            lblMsg.Text = string.Format("Time: {1}\t\tMessage: {0}", message, DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    private void ShowMessage(string message)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            // Add the message to a listbox of all messages
            listLog.Items.Add(string.Format("Time: {1}\t\tMessage: {0}", message, DateTime.Now));
        }
    }
}

public class MyCallBack : IServiceCallback
{
    public delegate void SendMessage(string message);

    public static event SendMessage AfterJoinServiceCallback;

    public void JoinServiceCallback(string message)
    {
        if (AfterJoinServiceCallback != null)
        {
            AfterJoinServiceCallback(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get your solution to work. But I got some help from a fellow student.

Comment: I have updated my answer to correct what I believe the original issue was and added a more complete example.